# Как в SQLite3 узнать какие даты присутствуют в столбце содержащим и дату и время?

Tags: node.js, sqlite3

Работаю с SQLite3 из под Node.JS
В таблице присутствует столбец с датой-временем в текстовом формате 'Feb 18 2021 11:06:37 GMT+0700'.
Так же в базе есть столбец utime - числовой, где тоже время представлено в unix-формате.
Может быть много (сотни) строк с одной датой, но разным временем.
Для фронтенда, мне надо:

1. узнать какие даты ('Feb 18 2021') присутствуют в таблице (чтобы знать сколько карточек будет)
2. Далее, получать строки принадлежащие одной дате, для заполнения карточек.
   Какими путями это достигается? параллельно RTFM-лю

Чтоб не терять времени на фронтЕ, пока я привязался к Unix времени:

1. получить список уникальных дат:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date(datetime(utime/1000, 'unixepoch','localtime')) AS dates
FROM events
ORDER BY utime
```

2. Подучить строки для указанной даты:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE date(datetime(utime/1000, 'unixepoch','localtime')) = '2021-02-18'
```

Как бы теперь прикрутить GMT - часовой пояс юзера?

Comment: *В таблице присутствует столбец с датой-временем в текстовом формате 'Feb 18 2021 11:06:37 GMT+0700'.* Это кто ж такой умный-то? перевод подобного формата во вменяемую дату-время в SQLite превратится в достаточно навороченное выражение... Будет в разы проще создать дополнительное поле и один раз отконвертироваться. *столбец utime - числовой, где тоже время представлено в unix-формате.* Ну это как раз элементарно - `SELECT DATE(utime, 'unixepoch')`

Comment: А `GMT+0700` у них у всех одинаковый?

Comment: GMT+0700 у всех одинаковый! полагаю что unixtime не содержит инфы о часовом поясе, поэтому такой изврат.

Comment: Не, а кто мешал при сохранении в SQLite использовать формат, который понимает этот самый SQLite? на зачем выдумали эту отшибленную фигню, с которой непонятно что делать? Если ещё возможно - уж лучше переделайте. пока поезд совсем не ушёл...

Comment: как учесть GMT в котором функционирует юзер?
вот я сконвертировал
SELECT DATETIME(ROUND(utime / 1000), 'unixepoch') AS isodate FROM events
Сформировались строки с временем в формате 2021-02-18 11:06:37
но в нём тоже нет GMT. Отдельную строку под GMT завести?
Пока можно многое менять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала определимся что есть что. Timestamp (метка времени) -- это точка на временной оси, когда произошло или произойдёт некое событие. Дата (и дата-и-время) -- это не совсем время, это интерпретация времени. В один и тот же момент времени (timestamp) даты могут быть разные в зависимости от часового пояса, используемого календаря и других условностей.

Дальше. Вас интересуют даты в часовом поясе пользователя? Чтобы их получить вам надо использовать функции дат, указав смещение часового пояса пользователя. Допустим есть некое событие в 1613692799, здесь нет никакого часового пояса, это просто точка на оси времени. Если интерпретировать эту точку как UTC дату, то получится `select date(1613692799, 'unixepoch')` -- 2021-02-18. А чтобы взглянуть на эту же точку из UTC+3 (московское время, например) надо накинуть эти 3 часика `select date(1613692799, 'unixepoch', '+3 hours')` -- 2021-02-19. Для жителя Лондона это 18-е, а для меня 19-е. Всё очень просто.

Хранить часовой пояс пользователя в большинстве случаев не нужно. Во-первых, дата может зависеть не от часового пояса пользователя, а от других факторов (например на авиабилетах мы хотим видеть дату-время в часовом поясе аэропорта на день вылета). Во-вторых, обычно пользователь может изменить таймзону по разным причинам (летом у жителя Лондона станет UTC+1), и тогда сохранённая зона возможно потеряет смысл.

Если вам надо создать объект даты у себя в коде, то вы можете так же использовать timestamp. То, что у вас в результате sql date(...) нет строчки "GMT+0700" не должно вас останавливать, для создания даты вам нужна метка времени.